# Linq-to-SQL combobox binding

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, linq-to-sql, combobox

I am trying to populate `combobox items` with `list of objects` that I retrieve from `linq to sql` in following way, (which only works for me with `select new`).

Note that the `Tax` parameters are exactly the same as the select new.

```
dt = new LilkaDataContext();
var taxes = from p in dt.Taxes select new
{
      Id = p.Id, 
      Name = p.Name,
      Percentage = p.Percentage,
      Note = p.Note

};
cb.ItemsSource = taxes;
```

XAML

```
<ComboBox Name="CbSettingsTax" Grid.Column="2" 
                              SelectedValue="Id"
                              DisplayMemberPath="Name" >
</ComboBox>
```

Now I need to parse the value and retrieve the Tax Id that is selected in combobox that I populated.

```
int selectedTax = ((Tax)CbProductTax.SelectedItem).Id;
```

And got following error because of `select new` creating new Object. I wonder if there is any way either to parse the last step to get `Tax.Id` or to better populate without `select new`/creating new object.

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType1`4[System.Int32,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal],System.String]' to type 'lilka.Tax'.

Edit:

```
dt = new LilkaDataContext();
var taxes = from p in dt.Taxes select p;
cb.ItemsSource = taxes;
```

Using this query I am unable to select item from Combobox Item list in GUI. It just does not appear as Selected Item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all let's talk about your ComboBox: you should use `SelectedValuePath` property instead of `SelectedValue`. So:

```
<ComboBox Name="CbSettingsTax" Grid.Column="2" 
                              SelectedValuePath="Id"
                              DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

In this way in your code `CbSettingsTax.SelectedValue` will return the Id value of the selected Tax object, while `CbSettingsTax.SelectedItem` will return the *whole* selected object.

About Linq-To-Sql, I see you are using "Query Syntax". Personally I prefer "Method Syntax". When you write

```
var taxes = from p in dt.Taxes select new
{
      Id = p.Id, 
      Name = p.Name,
      Percentage = p.Percentage,
      Note = p.Note
};
```

since you are using the new keyword, the compiler creates an [Anonimous Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) for you, which has 4 properties called Id, Name, Percentage and Note. Then LINQ copies Tax property values in the new class ones.

However **this anonimous type is not the same as `Tax` type**. Therefore you cannot cast it to `Tax`. Indeed taxes is a collection of this anonymous type. It is not a collection of Tax objects.

Previously I told you I prefer LINQ "Method Syntax", since every LINQ method returns a generic IEnumerable.
Of course you can obtain the same result with query syntax, but it is easy to mistake.

If you use (for example):

```
dt = new LilkaDataContext();
cb.ItemsSource = dt.Taxes.Where(tax => tax.Name.Contains("VAT"));
```

your combobox will have a collection of Tax objects as ItemsSource.

Now you just need to choose your approach. You can use "Method Syntax" and then remove the `SelectedValuePath` property from your combobox. On the other side you can continue using "Query Syntax", but in this case you have to use `SelectedValuePath` property and your code will be:

```
int id = (int)CbProductTax.SelectedValue;
```

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Just put the data directly from the query instead of creating a new object:

```
dt = new LilkaDataContext();
var taxes = from p in dt.Taxes select p;
cb.ItemsSource = taxes.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have tried to use this approach as well, but I am unable to select item from Combobox Item list in GUI. It just does not appear as Selected Item.